# Cannot Access SysML stereotypes and their properties in Acceleo

Tags: acceleo, sysml

I am developing a M2T generator in Acceleo (in Eclipse). The model is basically a UML model with SysML profile created in Papyrus. It includes Blocks and FlowPorts. I have to access these stereotypes but it seems that I cannot retrieve any SysML object even though they appear in list (code suggestion). Actually I have to access ‘Direction’ property of FlowPort associated with Port. I have already tried suggestions and answers from various forums (including https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/452587/) but in vain.

The code is given below. I have created java services as suggested by https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1060450&goto=1693765& but port.hasStereotype(‘FlowPort’) always return false. I have also tried ‘SysML::PortAndFlows::FlowPort’ instead of ‘FlowPort’. I use Acceleo 3.6.2 on Eclipse Mars.

```
...
[template public generateElement(model : Model)]
[comment @main/]

[file ('created.txt', false, 'UTF-8')]
[for(port: Port | model.eAllContents(Port))]
    [if(port.hasStereotype('FlowPort'))]
        OK
    [else]
        NOT OK
    [/if]
[/for]
[/file]
[/template]
```

I include following metamodels in the Module at the time of creating the module:

```
http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML
http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/0.7.0/SysML
http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/0.7.0/SysML/Blocks
http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/0.7.0/SysML/Constraints
http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/0.7.0/SysML/PortAndFlows
http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore
```

Also, I do register required packages including following in registerPackages() of Generate.java as suggested by the link just mentioned above.

```
    // UML2 profiles
    URI uri = URI.createURI("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources");
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.LIBRARIES_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("libraries").appendSegment(""));
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.METAMODELS_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("metamodels").appendSegment(""));
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.PROFILES_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("profiles").appendSegment(""));  

    // SysML profiles
    uri = URI.createURI("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml");
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI(SysmlResource.LIBRARIES_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("librairies").appendSegment(""));
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI("pathmap://SysML_PROFILES/"), uri.appendSegment("SysML.profile.uml").appendSegment("")); 
    uriMap.put(URI.createURI("pathmap://SysML_PROFILES/"), uri.appendSegment("model").appendSegment(""));
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem, but with UML/MARTE rather than SysML.

I bet that `port.getAppliedStereotypes()` always returns the empty list, no matter what (even if of course, port *is* stereotyped). I also tried everything you did, unsuccessfully, including double-checking if there was a `@generated NOT` in the javadoc of the `registerPackages` method (to it being re-generated each time).

I fixed the issue whit a little workaround. I assume that you (like I did) use as input for the transformation the model.uml file generated by Papyrus. This might actually be the cause of the problem, even though I don't see an alternative. If you open that file with a text editor, you'll find that the `<FlowPort>` tags are outside the `<uml:Model>` tag. This means that, for reasons that I still fail to understand, the `stereotype()` methods cannot "see" the stereotypes and always return null, or empty lists. This is possibly because they fail to match the stereotype `base_NamedElement` to the `xmi:id` inside the `<uml:Model>` tag.

On the other hand, if you define a template which takes as input a FlowPort (rather than a Model) you will be able to get your stereotyped element and all of its properties.

```
[template public generateElement(aFlowPort: FlowPort)]
[comment @main /]
[comment here you can access to the aFlowPort fields]
[/template]
```

Among others, you can also access the `base_NamedElement` property of the stereotype (i.e., the `Port` that is stereotyped `FlowPort` in your model), and you can use the `qualifiedName` property of the base element to map back the stereotype to the `Port` in your `Model`. In practice, this means that you have to link the stereotypes to their stereotyped entities by hand.

Clunky and annoying, but still gets the job done until somebody comes with a less "workaroundy" solution.

Comment: Hi st1led, Yes, I was using a papyrus generated uml model. I had already discovered your suggested work around but I am not sure if we can access all UML objects in that template (with FlowPort). For example can I access containing Class or Package object?

Comment: Once you access the `base_namedElement` of the `FlowPort`, i.e., a `Port`, you can navigate from the `Port` using the APIs for UML objects, such as `owner`, `ownedElements`, and so on. Is this what you are looking for?